# Ist "Stundenansatz des Auftragnehmern" korrekt?

Tags: grammaticality

Ich habe meine Abschlussarbeit von einem Experten korrigieren lassen.

Original war der Text:

> a = Stundenansatz des Auftragnehmers

Der Experte hat den Text umgeändert in:

> a = Stundenansatz des Auftragnehmern

Word scheint mit der Änderung nicht klarzukommen. Stimmt denn nun die Änderung oder nicht?

Comment: _"des Auftragnehmern"_ ist definitiv unkorrekt. Sofern _Plural_ in dem Kontext angedacht war, müsste es  _"der Auftragnehmer"_ heissen.

Comment: Was ist ein *Stundenansatz*? Ist vielleicht eher *Stundensatz* gemeint? Und nein: der Genitiv singular lautet *des Auftragnehmers*.

Comment: @Björn Ich würde unter _Stundenansatz_ die geschätzte Anzahl Arbeitsstunden eines Auftragnehmers für ein Gewerk vestehen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, ich habe gerade entdeckt, dass *Stundenansatz* eine schweizerdeutsche Variante von *Stundensatz* ist.

Comment: @björn _"des Auftragnehmern"_ ist trotzdem falsch, auch in Schweizerdeutsch, oder?

Comment: Ich habe vermutet, dass "Stundenansatz des Auftragnehmern" falsch ist, wollte aber sicherheitshalber eine Bestätigung haben. Danke euch beiden und ja, ich wohne in der Schweiz, deshalb "Stundenansatz" aber gut zu wissen, dass der Begriff nur auf Schweizerdeutsch korrekt ist!

Comment: Dein Experte ist keiner. Ignoriere seinen Rat.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: _Stundenansatz_ kann man so verstehen (erforderliche Arbeitsstunden für die Fertigstellung); es könnte aber in meiner Semantik auch der veranschlagte Stundenlohn sein. Ich kenne jedoch nur sehr wenig Schweizerdeutsch vom Zuhören.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is: Der Stundenansatz des Auftragnehmers.

The stumbling block is the word 'Stundenansatz. It is a German compound noun, probably pertaining to some hourly base charge or wage. "Des (of the) Auftragsnehmers" (order taker) is genitive, singular and grammatically correct in the original sentence. And so the English sentence could be: The base wage of the order taker. But it's a little unclear without context.

Auftragsnehmern is plural. It requires a different sentence structure, such as: Der Stundensatz, der den Auftragsnehmern (plural) zusteht, is $.. (The hourly wage for (of) the order takers is $...).

Comment: Wieso antworten Sie auf eine in Deutsch gestellte Frage auf Englisch?

Comment: Ergänzend: *Auftragnehmern* ist eindeutig Dativ (Plural).